# contact form7 generate unique id with no random

Tags: javascript, contact-form

```
/* Generate Quote Ticket */
function genTicketString() {
return substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 0, 8);
}
add_shortcode('quoteticket', 'genTicketString');
```

this function is work fine , but how to make ID with no random number
I need to display number from  00000001 - 999999999

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use a variable and increment it

```
let uniqueId = 0;

function genTicketString() {
  return uniqueId++;
}
```

But every time you page is going to get loaded the `uniqueId` will restart from 0.

If the restart is not ok, another solution is to ask the server to gives the uniqueId to you every time you need one.

```
function genTicketString(callback) {
  someAjaxRequest((err, uniqueId) => {
     // Handle error

     callback(uniqueId);
  });
}
```

Comment: sorry I dont understand where's to put  "let uniqueId=0;"  could you please write the full coding for me?

Comment: Just in top of it, like in my example. You gotta read about [what a scope is](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).